# Referenciar duplicata ou a pergunta em comentários e respostas?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Estava olhando algumas perguntas antigas minhas, e vi que tem uma pergunta feita depois, e que no caso seria uma duplicata da minha pergunta...

Essa é a [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237114/remover-uma-quantidade-n-de-dias-em-uma-data) que fiz, e essa outra pergunta marcada como [duplicata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261483/subtrair-data-de-um-datetime?noredirect=1&lq=1) que referencia a minha pergunta...

Então estive pensando, se algum dia eu responder uma pergunta ou deixar um comentário, deixo a referência a pergunta duplicata, que no caso também mostra um link da minha pergunta, ou a pergunta diretamente?

ou isso depende do tipo de pergunta que um usuário pode fazer?

ou é melhor marcar como referencia as duas perguntas?

Comment: Assim como o Maniero comentou na resposta, eu costumo verificar se as respostas da pergunta mais recente possuem algo de interessante que não há na original. Se tem, eu sinalizo a mais recente. Se só reproduz as respostas da original, eu sinalizo a original.

Answer (score 2):

Eu acho que depende. Tudo precisa de contexto para tomar a decisão correta. Normalmente o ideal é escolher a mais adequada para aquele caso. É muito comum ser mais a mais recente já duplicada porque ela tem sempre algo mais além da original, mas nem sempre. Se coloca a mais recente não costuma ser necessário colocar a original, mas pode ter caso é que melhor.

Você só pode sinalizar que a pergunta está duplicada, para votar precisa ter 3000 pontos.